# Grails GORM Constraint

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-orm

Given the following two domains:

```
class Follows {
    User followee
    ...
    static belongsTo = [follower: User]
}

class User {
    String name
    String lastName
    ...
    static hasMany = [ follows: Follows ]
    static mappedBy = [ follows: 'follower' ]
}
```

Which creates the following table:

```
+------+-------------+-------------+
|  id  | follower_id | followee_id |
+------+-------------+-------------+
| 1    | 1           | 3           |
| 2    | 3           | 2           |
| 3    | 2           | 1           |
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

Is there a way through *contraints* to prevent duplicates of *follower* - *followee*? I'm trying to prevent both directions, like, User Id 3 should not be able to *follow* the User ID 1 if the User ID 1 is already following the User ID 3.

**In other words, this is what I'm trying to prevent:**

```
+------+-------------+-------------+
|  id  | follower_id | followee_id |
+------+-------------+-------------+
| 1    | 1           | 3           |
| 2    | 3           | 1           |
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

I know I may be able of querying the database before insertion to check if User 1 is following 3 (or the other way around) and if true cancel the insertion, but I'm trying to avoid hitting the DB twice per *follow* operation.

Cheers and thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no existing constraint to handle such a case. You can create your own constraint, but it'd have to query the database, so there's no point.

But, you *can* use a unique constraint if you add a new property to `Follows` containing a unique value which applies to both following directions.

```
class Follows {
    User followee
    ...
    Integer someUniqueProperty

    static belongsTo = [follower: User]

    static constraints = {
        someUniqueProperty unique: true
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        someUniqueProperty = calculateUniqueProperty()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        someUniqueProperty = calculateUniqueProperty()
    }

    private Integer calculateUniqueProperty() {
       [follower.id, followee.id].sort().hashCode()
    }
}
```

In the example above, `someUniqueProperty` must be unique across all instances of `Follows`. Its value is set before inserting/updating an instance by putting `follower` and `followee` in a list, always in the same order, and then getting the hash code. This is based on the fact that: `[1, 3].hashCode() == [3, 1].sort().hashCode()`

In a nutshell, adding a unique property allows the database to enforce the constraint you need.

Comment: Although a more elegant solution like constraints usage would've been great, you solutions is so simple that is plain brilliant. Awesome answer! cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, my solution does use constraints. Look at the constraints closure in the example.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to a simple constraint to prevent duplicates on both directions instead of the use of hash. Btw, I tested it and it works perfectly.